# Getting Data::Dumper Object print error

Tags: perl, cpan, data-dumper

**Problem:**

I am trying to print the `$self` object to know the contained data structure like below line and getting the error:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $self = shift;
print Dumper($self);
```

**Error:**

```
Can't locate object method "FIRSTKEY" via package "Memoize::Expire" at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/Data/Dumper.pm line 158
```

**Version Information:**

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -le 'print Data::Dumper->VERSION';
2.121

$ perl -MMemoize::Expire -le 'print Memoize::Expire->VERSION';
1.03

$ perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 8 subversion 8) configuration:
  Platform:
    osname=linux, osvers=2.6.18-53.1.14.el5pae, archname=i386-linux-thread-multi
    uname='linux builder16.centos.org 2.6.18-53.1.14.el5pae #1 smp wed mar 5 12:07:47 est 2008 i686 athlon i386 gnulinux '
    config_args='-des -Doptimize=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i386 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -Dversion=5.8.8 -Dmyhostname=localhost -Dperladmin=root@localhost -Dcc=gcc -Dcf_by=Red Hat, Inc. -Dinstallprefix=/usr -Dprefix=/usr -Darchname=i386-linux -Dvendorprefix=/usr -Dsiteprefix=/usr -Duseshrplib -Dusethreads -Duseithreads -Duselargefiles -Dd_dosuid -Dd_semctl_semun -Di_db -Ui_ndbm -Di_gdbm -Di_shadow -Di_syslog -Dman3ext=3pm -Duseperlio -Dinstallusrbinperl=n -Ubincompat5005 -Uversiononly -Dpager=/usr/bin/less -isr -Dd_gethostent_r_proto -Ud_endhostent_r_proto -Ud_sethostent_r_proto -Ud_endprotoent_r_proto -Ud_setprotoent_r_proto -Ud_endservent_r_proto -Ud_setservent_r_proto -Dinc_version_list=5.8.7 5.8.6 5.8.5 -Dscriptdir=/usr/bin'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    usethreads=define use5005threads=undef useithreads=define usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define d_sfio=undef uselargefiles=define usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=undef use64bitall=undef uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='gcc', ccflags ='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/gdbm',
    optimize='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i386 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables',
    cppflags='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/gdbm'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42)', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=4, ptrsize=4, doublesize=8, byteorder=1234
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=12
    ivtype='long', ivsize=4, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=4, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='gcc', ldflags =' -L/usr/local/lib'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib /lib /usr/lib
    libs=-lresolv -lnsl -lgdbm -ldb -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc
    perllibs=-lresolv -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc
    libc=/lib/libc-2.5.so, so=so, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl.so
    gnulibc_version='2.5'
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=so, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags='-Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/CORE'
    cccdlflags='-fPIC', lddlflags='-shared -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i386 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -L/usr/local/lib'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: MULTIPLICITY PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT
                        PERL_MALLOC_WRAP USE_ITHREADS USE_LARGE_FILES
                        USE_PERLIO USE_REENTRANT_API
  Built under linux
  Compiled at Sep 17 2008 13:37:09
  @INC:
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.7/i386-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.6/i386-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5/i386-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.7
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.6
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.7/i386-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.6/i386-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/i386-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.7
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.6
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8
```

I can not update perl version, I have tried updating `Data::Dumper` with `cpan install Data::Dumper;`.

Which shows this `/usr/bin/make test -- OK` after installation.

But when I check again the version remains the same.

So Is there any way I can solve this problem?

Or I could use some other way to print the desired Object?

Comment: Perl 5.8.8 is now over 12 years old. Any chance you can upgrade?

Comment: The problem isn't with Perl or `Data::Dumper` - it's with `Memoize::Expire`. Looks like it isn't implementing all of the functions required for `tie`ing a hash.

Comment: @haukex: No I can't upgrade perl version, @Chris: `Memoize::Expire` is updated already but still I am getting this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This reproduces the `Can't locate object method "FIRSTKEY" via package "Memoize::Expire"` error (tested on Perl 5.26):

```
use Memoize::Expire;
use Data::Dumper;
tie my %cache => 'Memoize::Expire';
print Dumper(\%cache);
```

I think this could be considered a bug in [`Memoize::Expire`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Memoize::Expire): it doesn't provide the [`FIRSTKEY`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html#FIRSTKEY-this) and `NEXTKEY` implementations that [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) needs. You may want to report a bug in the [issue tracker](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Memoize), although unfortunately the distribution seems unmaintained for several years. (You might also want to consider your use of `Memoize::Expire` in the first place - what are you using it for, do you really need it, etc.)

Since `Data::Dumper` is typically used for debugging, my question would be if you really need to see the contents of the `Memoize::Expire` object. If so, you might consider switching to [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) because it provides [`Data::Dump::Filtered`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump::Filtered). While the following will **not** provide a data structure that can be `eval`ed back to Perl, it will hopefully give you useful debug output:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Memoize::Expire;
use Data::Dump;
use Data::Dump::Filtered 'add_dump_filter';

add_dump_filter sub {
    my ($ctx, $ref) = @_;
    if ($ctx->reftype eq 'HASH' && defined(tied(%$ref))) {
            return { comment=>"hashref tied to:",
                object=>tied(%$ref) };
    }
    return undef; # normal processing
};

tie my %cache => 'Memoize::Expire';
$cache{x}='y';
dd \%cache;
```

Output:

```
# hashref tied to:
bless({
  C => { x => "Z\x8C\25b\0\0\0\0\xFF\xFFy" },
  LIFETIME => 0,
  NUM_USES => 0,
}, "Memoize::Expire")
```

Finally, here's an IMO **ugly hack** quick fix with implementations borrowed from [`Tie::StdHash`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/Hash.html). This should get rid of the error but will however **not** show you the internal structure of the object:

```
sub Memoize::Expire::FIRSTKEY { my $a = scalar keys %{$_[0]{C}}; each %{$_[0]{C}} }
sub Memoize::Expire::NEXTKEY  { each %{$_[0]{C}} }
```

Comment: Thanks @haukex, This solved my problem, I will report this problem to 
 `Memoize::Expire`, Unfortunately `Memoize::Expire` is being used in some legacy codebase.

Answer (score 0):

`$self` is a tie'd object with some of the tied methods unimplemented. A workaround to dumping the tied object is to dump the underlying object

```
print Dumper(tied $self)
```

or in cases where it is ambiguous whether the object is tied or not

```
print Dumper(tied $self || $self)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is flawed in several places: 1. `$self` doesn't need to be tied nor an object (since `Data::Dumper` recurses); 2. `tied $self` should be `tied %$self` (since the error is regarding `FIRSTKEY`, we know it's not a tied scalar); and 3. to be applicable in general, `||` should be `//` (defined-or). https://gist.github.com/haukex/7da1940256716ec1ff6bd3f9c89814e5